# Int being read as text? Python

Tags: python, csv

I have scraped a website, and had the information saved into a CSV file. However parts of the information scraped are numbers, which when opened in excel, the cells first appear to be empty, and then require me to double click each cell before the data appears. Once the data is visible, it is not read as numbers, and instead seems to be read as text (or perhaps it's not even being read as text) as I also tried implementing text to int conversion on excel, and when I attempted to convert the text it simply deleted all information within the cells. 
Any help appreciated.

```
import math
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import requests
import re 
source = requests.get('https://www.example.com').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

csvfile = open('example.csv', 'wt', newline='')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow('')
    for teams in soup.find_all('span', class_="name ib"):
        writer.writerow(team)
finally:
     csvfile.close()

## Also if instead of saving the 2nd portion of the program starting from the 
## second csv open, and I  
## instead change the code to directly display the information in the 
## console, the entire html tag is displayed, not just the information inside 
## of the tag 



csvfile = open('example2.csv', 'wt', newline='')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow('')
    for odds in soup.find_all('span', class_=re.compile(r"price-val_.")):
       writer.writerow(value)


finally:
    csvfile.close()
```

### Excel screenshot

[image: [excel screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/L0KHGvW)]

Comment: Can you post an example row of the data from the csv file?

Comment: It's unrelated to your main question, but rather than using a `try`/`finally` pair to make sure your files get closed, use [a `with` statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). It does exactly the same thing in a much more concise way.

Comment: In my experience Excel is not good at importing data of different types from csv. Especially not date formats. You'd probably have better luck with creating an XML file that is excel readable and in it specify the type for every cell.

Comment: From what you describe I'd say you have new line characters surrounding you int in you csv-file. You probably haven't sanitized these before writing the file. You inspect this in excel e.g by doing a LENGTH() on your fields and see if that matches your ints. Or do a CODE(LEFT(excelField,1)). If I'm right you'll probably see 10 or 13 (new line characters depending on your OS).